# parameterized sql query issue

Tags: c#, sql

I have a csv from where I import data to a database.

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@cn", SqlDbType.Text);
myCommand.Parameters["@cn"].Value = comp.Rows[i][1].ToString();
```

In case the value of `comp.Rows[i][1]` is `X'496e626randomcharacters'` I receive this error: `The floating point value '496e626' is out of the range of computer representation (8 bytes). Incorrect syntax near '496e626'.`

It should be handled as string/text so I don't understand the floating point error.
What is wrong here?

Comment: How does the query look like?

Comment: Are you using a `DataTable`? What's the type of column [1]?

Comment: Have you tried using `AddWithValue("@cn", comp.Rows[i][1])`?

Comment: AddWithValue is more likely to suffer from implicit conversion problems than explicitly defining a parameter type.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'd say it's more likely to treat it as it's expected (a string).

Comment: Are you sure your Provider understands named parameters? Presumably yours just goes by Position and maps the parameter to the wrong placeholder in the sql.

Comment: When do you get the exception?

Comment: comp is a DataTable. I will share the query soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 SqlDbType.VarChar
```

rather than

```
 SqlDbType.Text
```

> `SqlDbType.Text`: String. A variable-length stream of **non-Unicode** data
>   with a maximum length of 2 31 -1 (or 2,147,483,647) characters.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@cn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=comp.Rows[i][1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is coming from the SQL Server, and happens whenever SQL tries to convert a string value into a numeric value.

You haven't shown any of the relevant SQL code, but I assume you are passing this value into a stored procedure, which is then inserting it into a data table. Both the parameter type and column type in the table needs to be `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` as well, or SQL will try to do the conversion.

Also, be careful about doing comparisons with your parameter against numeric values; for example, if you try to do a comparison like:

```
WHERE @CN = 1.234
```

SQL will try to convert your `VARCHAR` to a floating point value. You can use methods like `ISNUMERIC` to avoid the comparisons that are going to fail.